# How to make only one accordion slide open at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site I'm working on that is all based on accordion style slides. The problem is that the code I used does not close the open slides by default. I need it so that when you click one slide it opens and then when you click another it closes the first slide and so on. I posted all the JS from the page, what can I add to this to make it only allow one slide to be open at a time?

```
<script> 
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
$('#up').fadeIn();
} else {
$('#up').fadeOut();
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
$('#up').fadeIn(); 
} else {
$('#up').fadeOut(); 
}
});

$('#up').click(function(){

$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 800);  
});
</script>

<!-- Menu -->
<script>    
$('.link').click(function() {

var link = $(this).attr('href');
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(link).offset().top - 80}, 800);
});
</script>

<!-- Collapse Toogle -->
<script>      
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {

$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 105}, 800); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the class of the item clicked.

```
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {

    for (c=0;c<$('.collapse').length;c++){
        $("#"+$('.collapse')[c].id).collapse('hide');
    }

    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 105}, 800);
});
```

So when you click at a `.menu-item` you can get all `.menu-item-clicked` and change them to close.

Comment: I hate to ask this but how would you apply that to the page as it is now?

Comment: I would be willing to pay you to help me with this if that is ok. Is there some way I can PM you my email so I can send you the files?

Comment: If you look at the page I showed you, you can get the idea. I need everything to stay in a fixed area. When the other slides stay open it makes the page too long.

Comment: Can you check that email address, it bounced back

Comment: Did you get the email Claudio?

Comment: You are the man Claudio! You made my day go a whole lot better! Thank you for actually taking the time to help me and not criticize me like Arjan. This is my first time posting here and if it were just Arjan that answered I would not have come back.

Answer (score -1):

[jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) has some very useful widgets, including [accordions](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/). Please use that, instead of trying to recreate the behavior. (Unless you want to find out how it works, creating something for learning purposes is valid. But then your question should specify that.)

Comment: Its actually a template, the project needed to be a quick turnaround.. Im stuck with it. Its perfect except for that one missing function. I appreciate the advice but I really need to stick with this at this point.  DO you happen to know how I can do it?